# Hough transformation for circles and rectangle

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am looking to identify the circles in an image. The circles are the tyres of a vehicle that is present in the image. However, using Hough's transformation, many circles are appearing in the image, but not the ones around the tyres. Not sure if there is a better approach to the same.

Also, is there a way to identify the biggest rectangle in the image i.e. the vehicle's storage container.

Any pointers would be of great help.

Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to play with the parameters to filter out the unwanted circles.

**void HoughCircles(InputArray image, OutputArray circles, int method, double dp, double minDist, double param1=100, double param2=100, int minRadius=0, int maxRadius=0 )**

**minDist –** Minimum distance between the centers of the detected circles. If the parameter is too small, multiple neighbor circles may be falsely detected in addition to a true one. If it is too large, some circles may be missed.

**param1 –** First method-specific parameter. In case of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT , it is the higher threshold of the two passed to the Canny() edge detector (the lower one is twice smaller).

**param2 –** Second method-specific parameter. In case of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT , it is the accumulator threshold for the circle centers at the detection stage. The smaller it is, the more false circles may be detected. Circles, corresponding to the larger accumulator values, will be returned first.

**minRadius –** Minimum circle radius.
**maxRadius –** Maximum circle radius

Comment: I am new to both image processing and OpenCV. However, I did play around with the various parameter values. But lot of unnecessary circles are appearing. Also with the same parameter values, if the source image is changed, the circles change altogther. However, I would want this to work with any image I supply and it has to identify the tyres of the vehicle in the image.

Comment: parameters like minDist, minRadius, maxRadius will depend on how far the vehicle is from the viewpoint.
param1 and param2 are to adjust the edge detection threshold, which will depend on the contrast of the image taken specially at the tires. 
So in short you need to have some boundary conditions first. There is no algorithm in the world that will work perfectly for everything.
What you can probably experiment is try doing canny edge detection on the image first, play with the threshold to get proper edges around the tires then use that threshold in hough circles param1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can try 'Fast Circle Detection' algorithm on below paper.

[Fast Circle Detection Using Gradient Pair Vectors](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=5A327CF1B590510505D517B3658193C0?doi=10.1.1.121.9956&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I got very good result with it on my previous project, which was a real-time processing of finding the borders between iris and sclera of human eye.

hope this helps.

Comment: have you found any c/c++ implementation for this algorithm mentioned in this paper? Please share if you got any